# How to increase size of Raid 1 Allocation?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, software-raid, raid1

We had Raid 1 setup with two 1tb drives.  I have swapped out the drives and now it was on two 2tb drives, however, the raid array is still only 1 tb in size.  Is there a way to increase the size of the array without having to pull the data off and create a new array and put the data back on? Thanks in advance!

I ended up having to back up all the data with windows server backup.  Then destroyed the raid...rebuild it and it restored the data.  Everything worked fine.  I tried using qparted and extended the partition of each drive but that failed.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're going to have to back up the data, destroy the RAID1, create a new RAID1, and restore the data.

Comment: The answer to this is highly dependent on the RAID controller you're using and the filesystem riding on top of the array, but the general/safe answer is "Back everything up, rebuild the array, lay down a new filesystem and restore".  Even if you try to grow the array/filesystem "Back everything up" is still your first step.

Comment: So would windows server backup be sufficient enough to back everything up and restore?  Or is there a better way?